# Call a flask socketio event handler manually

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I have a function with a flask-socketio decorator. In a part of my app im using celery and in that process i want to call the function below the decorator

```
@socketio.on('Example')
@authenticated_only                            
def example(data):
    ...
```

the problem is that the event uses current_user inside, how could i emulate a regular call ? just for code eficiency so i dont have to recreate the exact same function inside a celery task.

I thought something like this:

```
@celery.task()
def celery_task:
    current_user=User.query.filter...
    example(data)
```

But im not certain about that solution and i dont even try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def basic_example(data, user):
    # do everything here

@socketio.on('Example')
@authenticated_only                            
def example(data):
    basic_example(data, current_user)

@celery.task()
def celery_task:
    user = User.query.filter...
    basic_example(data, user)
```